# ¿Cuál es el antónimo de "cacofonía"?

Tags: significado, sustantivos, solicitud-de-término, antónimos

El diccionario define:

> **[cacofonía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6ZYahLh)**
>
> Del gr. *κακοφωνία kakophōnía*.
>
> 1. f. Disonancia que resulta de la inarmónica combinación de los elementos acústicos de la palabra.

¿Existe alguna palabra que refleje el significado opuesto: palabras que combinadas suenen bien?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Eufonía**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H5llmUJ)

> Del lat. tardío *euphonĭa*, y este del gr. *εὐφωνία euphōnía*.
>
> 1. f. Sonoridad agradable que resulta de la acertada combinación de los elementos acústicos de las palabras.